# Providing the SecurityIdentity directly to a Quarkus/RESTEasy web service method

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

I am using Quarkus with RESTEasy to make a web service and I need access to the `SecurityIdentity` in some of my methods.

It is possible to get it injected by making the service `RequestScoped`:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {
    @Inject
    public SecurityIdentity securityIdentity;

    @GET
    public Foos getFoos() {
        // use securityIdentity
    }
}
```

But I would prefer to have the class `ApplicationScoped` and have the `SecurityIdentity` provided to the method instead. Something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    // This does not work, Quarkus tries to convert the request body to a SecurityIdentity.
    public Foos getFoos(SecurityIdentity securityIdentity) { 
        // use securityIdentity
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Is there a magic annotation I can put on to make Quarkus inject the `SecurityIdentity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping it injected into a field will still work for ApplicationScoped beans and be thread safe

Comment: Oh wow. Mind just blown. So SecurityIdentifyProxy is RequestScoped, but can still be injected into an ApplicationScoped bean, and this just works, threadsafe and all. I guess I have some reading to do. I still would have preferred to provide the SecurityIdentity to the method, since I think that signals the intent better, but I guess that is not the Quarkus/J2EE-CDI way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was the case in 2020 but adding the `@Context` annotation is working in 2023 for me. So the magic annotation you requested seems to be `@Context`

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    // Add the @Context annotation
    public Foos getFoos(@Context SecurityIdentity securityIdentity) { 
        // use securityIdentity
    }
}
```

The examples [in the documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference#standard-security-annotations) do not include injecting the `@Context SecurityIdentity` but do include injecting `@Context SecurityContext`. Maybe `SecurityContext` would be sufficient for your use case? If not, it seems `SecurityIdentity` can be used there too.